# Expected primary-expression before `alignas(X)`?

Tags: c++, c++11, alignment, alignas

I want to test the use of `alignas()`, so I write down these code:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename X> 
void user(const vector<X>& vx)
{
    constexpr int bufmax = 1024;
    alignas(X) buffer[bufmax];

    const int max = min(vx.size(), bufmax / sizeof(X));
    uninitialized_copy(vx.begin(), vx.begin()+max, buffer);
}
```

However, when I compile it with g++, the compiler outputs an error: "expected primary-expression before `alignas(X)`". Who could explain this? I don't know the exact usages of `alignas()`.

Comment: What is the type of `buffer`?

Comment: I guess it is `X`. These codes are come from the book The C++ Programming Language 4th edition.

Comment: I might have phrased this incorrectly. What part of line 9 specifies type of `buffer`? Also mandatory: What version of GCC do you use? Did you turn on C++11 features?

Comment: The version of GCC is 5.3.0, and yes, I turn on c++11 features. In fact, I am not sure the type of `buffer`, Is `alignas(X)` a declaration?

Answer (score 0):

`alignas(X)` is an aligment specifier, which is applied to type. Your error happens because you didn't specified a type here.

Judging from the rest of the code, you probably want to create aligned buffer of characters: `alignas(X) char buffer[bufmax];`

Answer (score 0):

add below data type to your code

```
char alignas(X) buffer[bufmax];

alignas(X) char buffer[bufmax];
```

I also bumped on the same while reading the book.